# pytest. Change default values of arguments of fixture

Tags: pytest, fixtures

Hi I have a fixture with default arguments, like

```
pytest.fixture(scope='function', params =[{'arg1':value1}, {'arg2':Value2}])
def some_fixture(request):
    if request.param['arg1'] == value1: 
       'do some actions'
    if request.param['arg2'] ==value2:
       'do some actions'
```

but now i see an error:

```
def some_fixture(request):
    if request.param['arg1']
       KeyError: arg1
```

Comment: Rather use [markers](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#using-markers-to-pass-data-to-fixtures) or [factories](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#factories-as-fixtures).